# In personalized page rank, should the page rank vector be initialized uniformly?

Tags: graph-theory, pagerank

In (normal) page rank, the (initial) page rank vector is usually initialized to the uniform distribution.

Should I do the same for **personalized** page rank? I wonder if I should initialize the page rank vector to the personalized teleportation vector.

In mathematical terms:

```
pi0 = starting vector at iteration 0 (a row vector)
pi = PageRank vector
H = row-normalized hyperlink matrix (n-by-n sparse matrix)
v = (personalized) teleportation vector (1-by-n row vector)
n = size of H matrix (scalar)
alpha = teleportation prob. (scalar, e.g. 0.85)
epsilon = convergence tolerance (scalar, e.g. 1e-8)
```

Usually, the starting page rank vector is usually set to the uniform vector:

```
pi=1/n*ones(1,n).
```

And then we run the power method:

```
while (not_converged):
     pi=alpha*pi*H + (alpha*(pi*a)+1-alpha)*v;
```

My question: **should I initialize `pi` with `v`?** (instead of the uniform vector)

Edit: one further consideration for the implementation is that `v` is usually quite a sparse vector (unlike the uniform vector `pi`). Using `v` might be better in terms of floating-point precision.

Comment: Mathematically, this should not make a difference, because the PageRank are steady state probabilities of the Google Matrix so they are independent from where you start. From a computational point of view, it does seem sensible to start using the personalised page rank probabilities to reduce number of iterations but I am not too sure about this

Comment: Can you please provide some relevant reference for the Personalised Page Rank?

Comment: @usεr11852 Personalized Page Rank (PPR) is the same as PR other
than the fact that jumps are
back to one of a given set of starting vertices (`v`), instead of the uniform vector. In a way, the
walk in PPR is biased towards (or personalized for) this set
of starting vertices and is more localized compared to the
random walk performed in PR.

Comment: @usεr11852 The algorithm is formally described in "Google's PageRank and Beyond: The Science of Search Engine Rankings", 2006,
Amy N. Langville, Carl D. Meyer

Comment: Thank you; it makes the question more self-contained!